# React Native Scatter Plot with Tags

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, plot, scatter-plot

I've found a couple of packages that provide some scatter plots for React Native like [react-native-scatter-chart](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-scatter-chart), [react-native-chart-kit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-chart-kit), [react-native-chartjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-chartjs) however I want to know If there is anything a bit more customizable.

I'm looking for a plot where I can add a few labels on the scatter points like in the following image:

[image]

Have you previously worked with something similar on React Native? Did you find any useful packages or developed a custom solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion the best JS library to do this is D3, with that being said;

Check this out: https://hswolff.com/blog/react-native-art-and-d3/

Basically you can use ART (of react-native) and D3 together to create lovely graphs. I'm not sure exactly what the limitations are, but it seems like the best option for now.

Comment: Note that ART is deprecated in Expo in favor of Svg now.